# What is the AMIS?

Tags: aircraft-systems

What is the Aircraft Maintenance Information System (AMIS)?

Online I found only a little information, in particular [here](https://fam.nwcg.gov/fam-web/help/amis/aviation_management_information_system.htm):

> The Aviation Management Information System (AMIS) is used to collect,
>   store and analyze information about the usage of aircraft within
>   Forest Service controls.

It is not clear if it is an embedded system, a general database, if it is still in use and where.

To be clear: I DO NOT want information regarding the AIMS (which is the brain of the IMA in the B777). I am looking for a different system called AMIS.

Comment: The first line of your question says "Aircraft Maintenance", but the link you posted calls it "Aviation Management". Which is it? My interpretation of the page you linked to is that it's a proprietary tool used in firefighting; see [here](https://fam.nwcg.gov/fam-web/help/famweb_help_1.htm). Or did you find some information that suggests it's something different?

Comment: [AMIS](http://www.amis.nl/en/over-amis/historie/) (Aircraft **Maintenance** Information System) is a ground commercial application based on Oracle SGDB. AMIS company in the Netherlands was created after the success of AMIS application, by their programmers. Don't mix with [AMIS](http://www.37000feet.com/report/1060560/B777-200-flight-crew-suffered-the-partial-loss-of-one-amis-aircraft) (Aviation **Management** Information System) a generic wording for tools onboard aircraft or on the ground.